# Can a Russian citizen return to Russia with an expired Russian passport, without getting into trouble?

Tags: passports, russia, regulations, russian-citizens

I'm sure I've read over the years about some western countries, definitely USA and perhaps some countries in Europe, or perhaps Australia, that it's your always your right as a citizen to come back to your country. And you only have to prove you're a citizen, even with no passport, let alone an expired passport.

But this doesn't necessarily mean it's the same in every country around the world.

So what about Russia? Is it a problem for a citizen to return with an expired passport, like a friend who was in my hostel in Latvia yesterday?

Comment: Does your friend have any other passport, or just the Russian one?

Comment: @AussieJoe: I think he only has the Russian one. But he's not here anymore to ask. In any case, AFAIK all countries require you to enter with their passport if you're a citizen that also has other passports.

Answer (score 7):

(Disclamer: this is a fairly sensitive topic, and I'm not a lawyer. If you have any doubts, seek legal help.)

In theory, the Russian constitution [states](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Constitution_of_Russia#Article_27) that Russian citizens always have the right to return to Russia. However, it's best to follow the standard procedures to avoid complications at the border or during the flight check-in. This depends on whether it's the internal or the foreign passport that has expired.

---

If your friend has an expired *internal* Russian passport he or she will need to apply for a new passport upon arrival, otherwise they'll face a penalty of up to 5000 RUB (~80 USD). The internal passport is normally not verified upon your departure or arrival so there should be absolutely no problems going back to Russia with an expired internal passport.

References: [Code of the Russian Federation on Administrative Offenses](http://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_34661/4945d985a14884048b5ab1caa49077aa6d0525a2/), [pravoved.ru](https://pravoved.ru/themes/prosrochennyj-pasport/).

---

If your friend has an expired *foreign* Russian passport, they need to get in touch with [the nearest embassy or consulate](https://www.kdmid.ru/docs.aspx) and (likely) fill in [the re-entry application](https://reentry.kdmid.ru/). [It should take 2 days](https://korea-seoul.mid.ru/uteran/prosrocen-zagranpasport-svidetel-stvo-na-vozvrasenie) for the re-entry certificate to be issued.

References: [rg.ru](https://rg.ru/2014/08/28/zagranpasport.html), [garant.ru](http://www.garant.ru/news/592269/).

Answer (score 4):

Timatic will note if a country allows its citizens to enter on expired passports. A quick check there indicates that "passports must be valid on arrival." A Russian embassy or consulate can issue such a person a certificate for returning to the Russian Federation, and probably replace the passport.

Comment: That is true of the US, too.  But Russia (like the US) may be reached by means other than air.  A Russian citizen in the EU with an expired Russian passport can travel to Russia by land.  What happens in that case?

Comment: @phoog Now that's a good question. I don't know offhand and my Russian doesn't seem to be good enough to do the required Internet searches.

Comment: Usually, most countries should accept any citizen showing up in border, provided they can prove that. process may be lengthy. But showing up at border is a challenge by Air, if airline won't accept you without a valid travel document.

Comment: @AnishSheela Yes this is true, but it is possible to get to Russia by land or sea also. For example one might enter by land from Finland, Latvia, or Ukraine, or take a ferry from Japan or Korea to Vladivostok and thus enter by sea.

Comment: This answer provides a solution for someone in the situation described in the question, but does not answer the question, which is "can a Russian citizen return to Russia with an expired Russian passport without getting in trouble."

Comment: My friend who prompted me to ask this question was here in Riga, Latvia and headed to Tallin, Estonia this morning. After Estonia he was hoping to cross the land border with Russia, but was worried about his expired Russian passport. I told him it should be no problem, but you never know since countries do not all have to have the same policies.

Comment: @hippietrail Even if your friend might be able to enter Russia with an expired passport, I would expect problems leaving Estonia. The friend is probably, right now, not allowed to stay in Estonia with the expired passport.

Comment: I agree w/ @Tor-EinarJarnbjo that the "friend" will not be allowed to travel on a plane with the expired passport, unless he has one from another country. If he does, he still could not get a Russian visa in it, unless he changed citizenship. Most likely this person will be denied entry until a certificate is issued by a Russian consulate outside of Russia. Even without a plane, and with land entry POE, Russia will still deny entry, since an expired passport is NOT a valid travel document.

Comment: @AussieJoe: He's not flying, he's crossing the land border from Estonia. Are you saying all countries deny entry to their citizens with expired travel documents, or only Russia? In either case can you provide a link or is this an assumption?